# How to connect GeoServer with Java to a PostGIS/PostGres database?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, open-source-gis, mapserver, java

I am having trouble using GeoServer to perform a shortest path analysis between two network points. My question is about connecting GeoServer with Java to a PostGIS/PostGres database.

I know that in MapServer we can use PHP functions like `PG_CONNECT` to connect and `PG_QUERY` to execute SQL queries... but what are the equivalent commands for GeoServer?

Comment: Please don't shout.

Answer (score 2):

for relatively fixed SQL Queries you can use the [SQL Views functionality](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/sqlview.html) for more dynamic queries you might need to look at using [WPS](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/install.html).